# Python3 pull date from MySQL comparison not working properly

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am pulling a row of information from a MySQL database table and comparing it with todays date to see if the data is from today or a different day.  For some reason when I compare what I pulled from the database to todays date it comes back as not equal.  The date being placed into the table came from the same datetime line from a different time that the script was ran, so I know the format is the same.  When I print 'today' and 'date' together they look identical but for some reason the If statement returns that they are not.  Just to test my if statement I just manually created the date variable instead of pulling it from the table and the if statement then works correctly.

**My Question:**  What am I doing incorrectly and how can I solve this?

**My Code(short version):**

```
from datetime import datetime
date = "2017-04-11"
today = (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
if today != date:
    print ("Dates did not match")
    print (today)
    print (date)
else:
    print ("Dates are equal")
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot explain exactly why it worked, if I convert 'date' to a string. I then do get that the values are equal.

```
from datetime import datetime
date, won, skipped, lumber, ore, mercury = read_db(record)
today = (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
if today != str(date):
    print ("Dates did not match")
    print (today)
    print (date)
else:
    print ("Dates are equal")
```